# Property to return the selected structure constant

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the selected value from a structure, so if the user selects "Custom", or "AD" authentication I will call a function to return the selected choice. I am using an additional property which attempts to return the selected constant. Basically what I want is to set `txtAuthentication.text = LoginDetails.Authentication`. When I do this I get an error that `LoginDetails.Authentication` cannot be converted to string. How should my properties be formed?

```
Public Class LoginDetails
Structure Authentication
    Const cCustom = "Custom"
    Const cActiveDirectory = "AD"

    Public ReadOnly Property Custom() As String
        Get
            Return cCustom
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property AD() As String
        Get
            Return cActiveDirectory
        End Get
    End Property
End Structure

Private Shared sAuthentionUsed As Authentication
Public Shared Property AuthentionUsed() As Authentication
    Get
        Return sAuthentionUsed
    End Get
    Set(value As Authentication)
        sAuthentionUsed = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign the type Authentication to a string property. Here's how I would do it.

```
Public Class LoginDetails
    Enum AuthenticationType
        Custom = 0
        AD = 1
    End Enum

    Private Shared sAuthentionUsed As AuthenticationType
    Public Shared Property AuthentionUsed() As AuthenticationType
        Get
            Return sAuthentionUsed
        End Get
        Set(value As AuthenticationType)
            sAuthentionUsed = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Select Case sAuthentionUsed
            Case AuthenticationType.AD
                Return "AD"
            Case AuthenticationType.Custom
                Return "Custom"
            Case Else
                Throw New NotImplementedException("Enum has no string representation: " & sAuthentionUsed.ToString())
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

Then use

```
txtAuthentication.text = LoginDetails.ToString()
```

I am sure someone will point out that you could cast the enum to a string to get the name, though.

Comment: I have changed in the Case statement the Return "AD" to Return "Active Dir" but when I set the label to lblAuthentication.Text = LoginDetails.AuthentionUsed.ToString I still get "AD". Any ideas?

Comment: Ok as you said LoginDetails.ToString() will get me the results. Is there a way to override ToString of a specific property?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question but my feeling is that no, you can't override the result of ToString() for a property. You should just have a function to return a string based on the property value, as in the example above.